# Search results show Angular placeholders as page titles

Tags: angularjs, seo

I've just uploaded my first angular site. When I check on Google to see whether it is indexed, I see this:

[image: site:paolopolichetti.it]

It is the dynamic angular code to set dynamic title/description.. How can I avoid this?!

Comment: Generic SEO advice is off topic on Stack Overflow, but the specific issue you are writing about is clearly *on* topic. I've edited the title to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make pages without hash fragments **crawlable**, you need to include  `<meta name="fragment" content="!">` tag in the head of the HTML of your page.

However, full good solution for your case could be https://prerender.io/

> The Prerender.io middleware that you install on your server will check
>   each request to see if it's a request from a crawler. If it is a
>   request from a crawler, the middleware will send a request to
>   Prerender.io for the static HTML of that page. If not, the request
>   will continue on to your normal server routes. The crawler never knows
>   that you are using Prerender.io since the response always goes through
>   your server.

As a custom solution you can use **fallback pages**

> In case the requesting resource doesn’t parse JavaScript, Fallback
>   pages which as HTML pages are displayed instead. Fallback pages which
>   are basically static pages typically try to replicate the
>   functionality and content of JavaScript web application by way of the
>   server-side rendered pages. These pages do comprise of the same
>   content that the JavaScript application would show in addition to
>   making use of standard index-able links for navigation.

http://www.promotejs.com/seo-strategies-for-javascript-heavy-single-page-applications-or-ajax-sites/

Comment: I'm using a hosting provider.. I don't think I can manage to install the middleware on their server. Am I wrong? How can I do this? Sorry but I'm not so experienced in this field..

Comment: I see you have node modules used, does your provider support node.js?

Comment: I don't think so.. This is my hosting provider (http://www.vhosting-it.net/web-hosting-low-cost.php). My plane is the "Personal 01"

Comment: I see it has .htaccess file support you can try apache integration https://gist.github.com/thoop/8072354

Comment: After I edit my .htaccess with infoes above what I've to do more? What lines of code to add to index/app files?

Comment: You just need to sign up and get account for your website. Make sure you change example.com to your domain.

Comment: This is what I've done:

- Set `<meta name="fragment" content="!">` tag and `<base href="/">` into the `head`

- Set `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true); $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');` into the .js

- Edited all links in the right way

- Edited `htaccess` with the code above and a rewriting rule for the wrong urls.

Is it all? It needs something else? 

Thanks :)

Comment: Did you add access token to htaccess file? You will get on after sign up.

Comment: Yes.. Here is the line: `RequestHeader set X-Prerender-Token "Here_is_my_token"`

Is it correct?

Comment: Then you are done, check if http://service.prerender.io/http://example.com works for you...

Comment: It works but it fails to load stylesheet and some other things.. is it normal?

Comment: Yes it is, it is just used to load cached html, resources will be loaded from website.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot dude.. When can I check if google updated infoes? How many times it needs?

Comment: Try to ask Google webmaster tools to crawl your website and it should be updated less than in a day, maybe realtime.